# How to imitate mouse events with full functionality in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent, keyevent

I am trying to remote control a Qt application over UDP messages from my host computer.

Currently, the remote controlled computer runs a Qt application that receives messages and creates Mouse Events. Host computer sends type, button, modifier and position (between 0 and 1) whenever there is a new Mouse Event. I am trying to create events with these values in remote controlled computer and imitate them just like they are created by a user.

```cpp
void MainWindow::slotNewMouseEvent(MouseMsg msg)
{
  auto point = scalePoint(msg.x, msg.y);    // basic conversion for coordinates

  switch(msg.type)
  {
  case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
    QTest::mousePress(this->childAt(point), (Qt::MouseButton) msg.button,
                    (Qt::KeyboardModifiers) msg.modifier);
    break;
  case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
    QTest::mouseRelease(this->childAt(point), (Qt::MouseButton) msg.button,
                      (Qt::KeyboardModifiers) msg.modifier);
    break;
  case QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick:
    QTest::mouseDClick(this->childAt(point), (Qt::MouseButton) msg.button,
                       (Qt::KeyboardModifiers) msg.modifier);
    break;
  case QEvent::MouseMove:
    QTest::mouseMove(this->childAt(point), point);
    break;
  default:
    break;
  }
}
```

```cpp
void MainWindow::slotNewMouseEvent(MouseMsg msg)
{
  auto point = scalePoint(msg.x, msg.y);    // basic conversion for coordinates

  QMouseEvent *evt = new QMouseEvent((QEvent::Type) msg.type,
                                      point,
                                      (Qt::MouseButton) msg.button,
                                      (Qt::MouseButtons) msg.buttons,
                                      (Qt::KeyboardModifiers) msg.modifier);

  qApp->postEvent(this->childAt(point), evt);

  // I was expecting funcionalities like this one to be done automatically
  if(evt->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick || evt->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
    this->childAt(point)->setFocus();
    }

  qApp->processEvents();

}
```

Both of these functions gives almost same results which is not desired. I was expecting sending newly created events to the top widget on screen would work. However, some functionalities like setting focus on clicked element, opening context menu by right click or selecting elements of a combobox (elements window is not a widget) does not work.

Is there a solution with keeping those events in remote controlled computer's Qt application? I would prefer not using system libraries like "windows.h" to prevent harms to the system and making my application cross-platform. Do I have to use them?